# Webelement parsing

Tags: java, selenium

So I was pulling information from this [Website](https://langara.ca/programs-and-courses/programs/computer-science/program-curriculum.html) and it was running really slow. `List<WebElement> listofprogramrequirements = row.findElements(By.className("course-selection-title"));` I am assuming I need a single object and to pull my information from the row. **Tr-> course-selection-> course-numbers.**

```
    WebElement tableelement = 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("table")));
    List<WebElement> trs = tableelement.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    for (WebElement row : trs) 
    {
        List<WebElement> listofprogramrequirements = row.findElements(By.className("course-selection- 
        title"));
        for (WebElement col : listofprogramrequirements) 
        {
            System.out.println(col.getText());
            List<WebElement> coursenumbers = row.findElements(By.className("course-number")); 
            if(coursenumbers.size()>0)
            {
                Iterator<WebElement> iter = coursenumbers.iterator();
                // This will check whether list has some element or not
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    WebElement item = iter.next();
                    String label = item.getText();
                    System.out.println(label);
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }

  **Produces:**
  All of
  CPSC 1050
  CPSC 1150
  CPSC 1160
  CPSC 1181
  CPSC 2150
  MATH 2362
  Two of
  One of
  MATH 1171
```

Comment: could you elaborate your question?

Comment: My code runs incredibly slow for what it is supposed to do. Is there a way to rewrite this to increase the speed. I need to grab the course-select, course-numbers to write out what it produces above. After the first loop it goes slow.

Comment: The website has a table which I need to grab the all the tr/td colspan="2", from there I grab the course-selection class name and then grab all the course-numbers while printing the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply your code by locating `course-selection-title` directly and use it to locate the courses under it

```
List<WebElement> listofprogramrequirements = driver.findElements(By.className("course-selection-title"));
for (WebElement col: listofprogramrequirements) {
    System.out.println(col.getText());
    List<WebElement> coursenumbers = col.findElements(By.xpath(".//..//td[@class='course-number']"));
}
```